# SSRS data driven subscription error

Tags: sql, reporting-services, business-intelligence, ssrs-2012

I have a data driven subscription with 71 parameters. Every-time I run my subscription I get 5 errors and 71 of 71  processed with 5 errors. But when I count my report only 66 reports have been created. I tried to check the log  but couldn't find any errors other than  `at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.RevertImpersonationContext.Run(ContextBody callback)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ExtensionClassFactory.CreateExtensionObject(Extension extConfig, Boolean typeOnly).
library!ReportServer_0-43!3b10!11/10/2015-11:46:20:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
library!ReportServer_0-43!411c!11/10/2015-11:46:20:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.LogonFailedException: Logon attempt for user 'user' failed., Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.LogonFailedException: Log on failed. Ensure the user name and password are correct. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The user name or password is incorrect
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.LoginUtil.Login(String userName, IntPtr ptrPwd, String domain)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.LoginUtil.Login(String userName, SecureStringWrapper userPwd, String domain)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ImpersonationContext..ctor(String userName, SecureStringWrapper password, String domain)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;`
Am I missing something,not reading the log properly? any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go to every related datasource of your report and check for invalid credentials/logins info.

Comment: I checked and confirmed it is correct, the confusing part is all 66 reports are running only 5 are giving errors where all my credentials are same through out the entire database. Thanks.

Comment: are The 66 reports using the same database? and being generated at the same time?

Comment: bro can you check this post if this helps you https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f8391ef0-601c-46cd-8cc0-6e07bffe2d9a/datadriven-subscription-stop-running-suddenly-without-any-error-message?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: You should manually identify which of the 5 runs are failing. It will most likely be the same 5. Then try and run the report for those instances manually and see what is the error it gives or if it runs fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To identify which logs are failing, you can view the report server's execution logs:

```
Use ReportServer
select * from ExecutionLog order by TimeStart DESC
```

The 'ReportID' field can be looked up in the reportserver's 'catalog' table.  I find that having an SSRS report set up that queries this is invaluable.

Once you identify the reports that are failing (via the above queries)  then you can try running them manually, to see if they work.  If they do work,  then set up a subscription for just those reports, and see if they work when run as a subscription.

If you've never had a problem with these before, my bet is that the datasources use pass-through authentication, which works when logged in, but not when run automatically.

Let us know how you get on!

Comment: very useful information! Thank you, but for some reason the errors are not shown on the table, the only log it shows is when the subscription was created two months ago.